# MS Access set combobox values from query

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access, combobox

I'm working with MS Access.

```
Private Sub Combo0_Change()
    Dim db As Database
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Dim SQL As String
    SQL = "SELECT album FROM Albums"

End Sub
```

I have a query and it returns an array, I need to store returned value into comboBox named owners.

I have tried

```
owners.RowSource = SQL
```

but after this all I get is one record at comboBox and it is "SELECT album FROM Albums".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, just set the **row source** of your dropdown control to your query.

Comment: I know this is quite old but can you set multiple queries to a value list of a combo box? Or, every item in the value list of a combo box tied to it's own separate query?

Comment: If you mean combining multiple lists into a single combobox, then use a UNION query.